Opening locally running Angular Site on other devices in Network?
I'm running Angular Web Site on my local machine.
I run the command on vs code terminal
ng serve -o
Its automatically bundles my website and open the link http://localhost:4200/
Is there any way, that I can open the same website on my mobile phone as well?

I tried it with a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server it works but I need to add a package and manually run it for a site. Secondly it just host files not the bundled Angular Web Site.

Someone referred me this blog post but Its complex and require extra setup.



Maybe run it with ng serve --host 0.0.0.0. That will let you load the site outside of localhost. On your mobile device, open a browser and set the url as something like http:://YOUR_SERVER_HOSTNAME:4200. You device and the server should be on the same network or the device should be able to resolve YOUR_SERVER_HOSTNAME.

YOUR_SERVER_HOSTNAME ???
I'm working on my laptop, not on a server.

Same applies - put your laptops hostname or ip address. Depending on your laptop, you may need to adjust your firewall.

It works and additionally its @angular/cli automatically makes http link for you. No need to worry about host name
Screenshot

If you are using an Android phone, you can try remote debugging Android devices.

Enable USB debugging on your Android phone
Connect your phone to you laptop via USB cable.
Open chrome browser on your laptop and go to chrome://inspect/#devices
Check Discover USB devices, write your address in Port forwarding settings and enable Port Forwarding.
Open chrome browser on your phone, there you can simply use locahost.
http://localhost:4200/

detailed guide: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging

Its works but the additional step is Enabling Port Forwarding.
Its was unchecked by default.
Screenshot

Yeah, I Added enable port forwarding in 4 step.
